# The number of (at most) $n-1$ distinct integers $1\le x_1,\dots,x_k\le p$ is at most $n^kp^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k>n\ge1$ be integers.

I have to estimate the number of choices for the numbers $x_1,\dots,x_k$, supposing that $1\le x_j\le p$, for an integer $p$ and that there are at most $n-1$ distinct numbers between the $x_j$'s.

So, let's count: having at most $n-1$ distinct numbers, imply that I have to choose at most $n-1$ values between $1$ and $p$. Thus $p^{n-1}$.

Next I have to count all the different choices I can take for my $x_j$'s: therefore I have to count in how many ways I can assign $n-1$ values to $k$ objects: this should be the number of positive integer solutions $(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})$ to the equation $y_1+\cdots+y_{n-1}=k$.

This is the missing link between me and the estimate written in the book, which is $n^kp^{n-1}$.

Can somebody help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p^{n-1}$ is a reasonable approximation which is accurate as long as $n \ll p$.  The correct value is ${p \choose n-1}=p(p-1)(p-2)\ldots (p-n+2)$.  Having chosen the acceptable values for the $x_j$s, each of them has $n-1$ possibilities, so you would have $(n-1)^k$ ways to assign them, which they are probably approximating by $n^k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have two questions: $\binom{p}{n-1}=\frac{p!}{(n-1)!(p-n+1)!}=\frac{p(p-1)\dots(p-n+2)}{(n-1)!}$, did you missed the $(n-1)!$ in the denominator?
However, we can simply note that what you wrote is greater than $\binom p{n-1}$, so we are ok. Thanks again.